# Cannot get glx to work after changing from Nvidia to Nouveau drivers FC24

Tags: fedora, opengl, nouveau

I run FC 24 (just upgraded from FC 23).

After the upgrade there were some issues with the X server, and so I decided to change from Nvidia proprietary drivers to Nouveau. Everything seems OK, except that I can't get GLX to work. For

```
glxinfo
```

I get:

```
name of display: :0.0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

A bunch of times, and then

```
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

For errors in Xorg.0.log, specifically for

```
less /var/log/Xorg.0.log |grep EE
```

I get:

```
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    86.925] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    93.381] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so: undefined symbol: _glapi_check_multithread)
[    93.381] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[    93.389] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: _glapi_check_multithread)
[    93.389] (EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
```

In Xorg.1.log, there is:

```
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   246.220] (EE) module ABI major version (6) doesn't match the server's version (9)
[   246.220] (EE) Failed to load module "glx" (module requirement mismatch, 0)
[   246.221] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
```

I do have mesa-libGL installed.

Any ideas?

P.S.: As a sideshow, there also is something somewhere that still calls the 'nv' module instead of nouveau. But given that there is no xorg.conf anymore, but it's all de-centralized in xorg.conf.d, I can't figure out where that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poked around on Rpmfusion and found a few more steps to take, to remove garbage left behind by the NVIDIA installer.

https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia#Recoverfromnvidia_installer

Namely:

```
rm -f /usr/lib{,64}/libGL.so.* /usr/lib{,64}/libEGL.so.*
rm -f /usr/lib{,64}/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
dnf reinstall xorg-x11-server-Xorg mesa-libGL mesa-libEGL
mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.saved
```

The last line was probably not necessary in my case, but the others likely were.

Seems to work now (for example `glxgears` shows spinning gears).